# session management in Jsp while using spring mvc

Tags: hibernate, session, spring-mvc, authorization

I have two entity classes `User(userId,userName,password)` and `Role(roleId,roleName)`. There is bidirectional one to many mapping between User and Role. Role of any User is either user or admin in database.

I have 4 jsp pages, "login.jsp","Hello.jsp","error.jsp","admin.jsp".I want that "Hello.jsp","admin.jsp" can be accessed only when the session is set after login is successful. Further I want that "admin.jsp" can be accessed by only admin while "Hello.jsp" can be accessed by both.

How can i do that.I'm a newbie in spring,hibernate.

My controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/record")
public class MainController {

    @Resource(name="userService")
    private UserService userService; 

    @Resource(name="roleService")
    private RoleService roleService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String GetFront(Model model){
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String PostFront(Model model){

        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/admin")
    public String Front1(Model model){
        return "admin";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/Hello")
    public String Front2(Model model){
        return "Hello";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/authenticate",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String authenticate(@RequestParam("uname")String userName,@RequestParam("pass")String password,Model model){

        boolean success = userService.validate(userName,password);
        if(success==true){
            return "Hello";
        }
        else{
            return "error";
        }

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getRecords(Model model) {

        List<User> users = userService.getAll();

        List<UserDTO> userDTO = new ArrayList<UserDTO>();

        for (User user: users) {
            UserDTO dto = new UserDTO();

            dto.setUserId(user.getUserId());
            dto.setUserName(user.getUserName());
            dto.setPassword(user.getPassword());
            dto.setRole(roleService.getAll(user.getUserId()));

            userDTO.add(dto);
        }

        model.addAttribute("users", userDTO);
        return "record";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAdd(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("userAttribute", new User());

        return "addUser";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postAdd(@ModelAttribute("userAttribute") User user) {

        userService.add(user);
        return "redirect:/record/list";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getDelete(@RequestParam("id") Integer userId) {

        userService.delete(userId);
        return "redirect:/record/list";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEdit(@RequestParam("id") Integer userId, Model model) {

        User user1 = userService.get(userId);
        model.addAttribute("userAttribute",user1);

        return "editUser";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postEdit(@RequestParam("id") Integer userId, 
                                @ModelAttribute("userAttribute") User user) {

        user.setUserId(userId);
        userService.edit(user);
        return "redirect:/record/list";
    }

}
```

Comment: The Hibernate, Session and Session-Cookies tags are not relevant to this question.  For what its worth, your users could be in an LDAP store and authentication information could be passed in HTTP headers instead of cookies.

Comment: I want to perform session management without using Spring Security

Comment: Then write a Servlet Filter that intercepts every request, checks the HTTP Session for the current user's flag and allows or denies each request.

Comment: Note that Spring Security does not manage HTTP Sessions (as defined by the Java EE Spec); session management is up to the servlet container.  So, if you have any concerns about Spring Security messing up with sessions or their lifecycle, rest assured, Spring Security will not be a bottleneck.  You will realize as the application grows that a simple servlet filter becomes far more unmanageable than using Spring Security from the beginning.  Otherwise, servlet filters are the way to go; that is what Spring Security also uses internally.

Answer (score 0):

Add [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) to the app.  The documentation has all the information you need in order to configure your app for restricting access to resources based on user roles.